# Location Constraint Offset In Wrong Position

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I would like a bone to copy the location of another bone, but I would also like to be able to manually edit the location later if need be. However, under the copy location constraint, every time I check "offset" it messes up the location. I've tried every combination I could think of. How do I get it to copy location and allow offset without it messing up the location? Here is a video of the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIZurcSZR_8&ab_channel=BehindTheScenes

Thank you for your time! It doesn't seem to have this problem with the copy rotation constraint, it's only copy location. Here is a link to the raw file if that helps debug:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ljo1JoQUSbHEUyzfkdM01pIWh3csiYWZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So at what position were you expecting the bone to be? If you click on Offset it will still copy the location but with an offset. When you're talking about editing the location, you're talking about editing it in Pose mode?

Comment: I'm expecting the bone to be in the same location as it's target. So, in my example I want the bone to follow the position of the hand. When both targets are set to world position, it's in the right place. The position only messes up when offset is checked. And, yes, I need offset to be able to move it in pose mode. But, when offset is changed it gets the world position wrong and sends the bone to a completely different location :(